# unlocking std::unique_lock without destroying it

Tags: stl, thread-synchronization

If create a unique_lock as below, can I unlock it without destroying or getting out of scope? In other words is this safe/acceptable?

```
std::mutex queueMutex;

// My understanding is that this locks the mutex
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(queueMutex); 
{
     // My critical section
}

//  Is it unlocking it properly, or do I have to pop it from the stack?
lk.unlock();
```

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe and acceptable, calling `unlock()` will unlock the mutex and make the `unique_lock` to forget about it so it does not unlock it again in the dtor.

Having said that, scoping is preferable in most cases for readability because if the function/scope is long and `unlock` is inside an `if` or another conditional construct it might be hard for the reader to follow.